# Blazor: How to Use a Select Option Razor Component for Multiple Enum Classes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, blazor

I have a **select option component** that binds and populates values for a **specific enum class**. However, I want the same component to work for another enum class too. I tried to modify the component and use `typeof` and `dynamic` but it did not work. How can I re-use the same select option component for multiple enum classes?

**Calling the component in my pages:**

```
<SelectEnumComponent @bind-EnumProperty="@driver.DriverType"
                            EnumType="@(typeof(DriverType))"/>
```

**Select Option Component:**

```
// SelectEnumComponent.razor

    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" 
                value="@EnumProperty"
                @onchange="OnValueChanged">
            @foreach (var type in Enum.GetValues(EnumType))
            {
                <option value="@type">@type</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>
    
        @code {
    
            [Parameter]
            public dynamic EnumProperty { get; set; }
    
            [Parameter]
            public EventCallback<dynamic> EnumPropertyChanged { get; set; }
    
            [Parameter]
            public Type EnumType { get; set; }
    
            private Task OnValueChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
            {
                EnumProperty = Enum.Parse(EnumType, e.Value.ToString(), true); // case insensitive
                return EnumPropertyChanged.InvokeAsync(EnumProperty);
            }
        }
```

**Enum Class - PropertyType:**

```
public enum PropertyType
    {
        [Display(Name = "String")]
        String,
        [Display(Name = "Numeric")]
        Numeric,
        [Display(Name = "Double")]
        Double,
        [Display(Name = "Enumeration")]
        Enumeration,
        [Display(Name = "Boolean")]
        Boolean
    }
```

**Enum Class - DriverType:**

```
public enum DriverType
    {
        [Display(Name = "WEB API")]
        API,
        [Display(Name = "Device")]
        Device,
        [Display(Name = "SSD")]
        SSD
    }
```

**Error:**

```
error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback<SharedModels.DriverType>' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback'
```

Comment: These error messages in Visual Studio about EventCallback are pretty buggy.  Does your code not compile and run?

Comment: Yes, the code does not compile or run.

Answer (score 2):

I test with both enums and it can work.I use `EnumProperty` rather than `@bind-EnumProperty` in the demo and I'm using .net 5:

razor:

```
      <SelectEnumComponent EnumProperty="@driver.DriverType" EnumType="@(typeof(DriverType))" />
        <SelectEnumComponent EnumProperty="@driver.PropertyType" EnumType="@(typeof(PropertyType))" />
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public Driver driver { get; set; } = new Driver();

}
```

Driver:

```
public class Driver
    {
        public DriverType DriverType { get;set; }
        public PropertyType PropertyType { get; set; }

    }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: I used `EnumProperty` rather than `@bind-EnumProperty` as you said but  I don't get the changed value on the parent page. I have a list of `Driver` that I iterate using `foreach` which I use the select component for each `DriverType` property. What do you think it's the reason is not updating? When I reset the component code to work with only one enum, the binding works and I get the changed value on the parent page.  Could it be the `EventCallback` in the component is not working and therefore not updating the value to the parent page if not using `@bind-EnumProperty`?

Comment: What is the version of your project?You mean if you use dynamic and typeof in your code,you will always get `cannot convert from 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback<SharedModels.DriverType>' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback'`

Comment: I'm using .NET 5 for my project. Yes true, I tried to overcome the error but I was not able to. Have you tried using a list and see if the values are updated in the list when you change the select option?

Comment: If I reset my select component code to work with only one enum class, I can update my list whenever I change the text input or select option: `@foreach (var driver in Drivers.Select((value, i) => new { i, value }))
{
 <InputComponent @bind-Data="@driver.value.DriverName"/>
 <SelectEnumComponent @bind-EnumProperty="@driver.value.DriverType"/>
}`. I think I will create a select option component for each enum class to make sure the updating of options is working

Comment: You can see my picture,after `select` is changed,it will refresh foreach.

Comment: I think the `@bind-EnumProperty` is required for the `EventCallback` to work and update the values. I will mark your answer as useful for your effort. Thank you @Yiyi.